# Передача DateTime в URL методу

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть метод контроллера сервера `Refresh(DateTime? Date)`
Есть метод jQuery который отправляет ajax-запрос по URL наподобие 
`http://localhost:1234/Home/Refresh?Date=23.04.2018%2022%3A30%3A12`(тут время кодируется в URL).
В метод `Refresh` приходит `null`. Я рассчитывал, что данные будут автоматически декодироваться.
Что сделать чтобы время передавалось верно?

Comment: Передавайте в виде Unix Epoch или же пользуйтесь ISO 8601, но и там, и там придётся парсить вручную.

Comment: Используйте `POST` вместо `GET`,  второе строка у вас кодируется два раза, не нужно кодировать строку в ручную, от сюда у вас `null`.
Прикрепите пример - код запроса Ajax к серверу.